# Is it a good choice to join a sandwich doctorate (doctoral stay)?

Tags: phd, research-process, chemistry

I am currently writing my dissertation for master's degree course and I intend in the future to join a sandwich doctorate in my field.

Do you have any experience to share?

What advice would you suggest to me?

Comment: An online definition I found. A Doctoral Stay is a stay you do in a different university than the university you registered in. For example, you are studying in a PhD at  University A and you come for a 6-months stay in the laboratory of the University B.

Comment: It's hard to advise unless you tell us what you're trying to achieve by doing this.

Comment: I intend to bring to Brazil some electrochemistry forensic skills and ideas that we haven't worked yet. Edit: I looked for people in this field on the internet and I found most of these researchers are from England and North America

Answer (score 13):

Sandwich doctorates are used in countries without developed higher education to bring their academic elite up to high international levels while limiting the costs. More importantly, since a full doctorate can last about five years, the graduates of a sandwich program will spend considerable time in their country and are less likely to grow roots in the host country. They can also maintain family ties better.

In Uruguay some ten years ago, the sandwich programs worked out well for all parties. The students would probably have become better researchers if they had stayed longer in their host institutions, but the goal was to develop the local capabilities.

In short, sandwich doctorates are a good, reasonable way for the student to get a good doctorate. In many cases, they would not be able to be accepted in the host program otherwise.

Answer (score 3):

First, I have no experience with this. But you asked for advice, also.
One consideration you will need to face is whether you get sufficient good advising, either locally or at the host institution, or preferably both. This is something you will probably need to work continuously to attain. Along with this, make sure that language isn't a serious issue.

Depending on what communication facilities are available you might also miss out on group discussions and seminars. This might matter or not, depending on local resources and also on your own ability to work independently. People differ greatly on that last point.

Second, since your field is Chemistry, you need to be assured that you will have adequate (lab) facilities to carry out any research. This might be easy or hard, depending on what is locally available to you, but make sure you know that you will have the needed materials.

Good luck.

---

Note that I taught in a doctoral program in which students were dispersed widely throughout the US (mostly). We met as a group once a month for the sorts of things that couldn't be done over the internet. It worked because we had a continuous connection among students and faculty in which all participated. It wasn't what you are looking at, but note that communication was key. (Labs weren't an issue as this was CS.)